# TypeError: 'unicode' object is not callable

Tags: python, selenium, unicode, phantomjs

I want to get the source but I have the `ERROR`:

```
>> from selenium import webdriver
>> driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
>> url='http://google.com'
>> cont=driver.page_source(url)
>> print cont
>> driver.quit()
```

ERROR:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "u.py", line 6, in <module>
    cont=driver.page_source(url)
TypeError: 'unicode' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

page_source is not a method in the way you're using it. You want to use the get method on a url and then the driver will contain the source code you're looking for.

```
>> from selenium import webdriver
>> driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
>> url='http://google.com'
>> driver.get(url)
>> print driver.page_source
```

Comment: I used `print cont.page_source` the the error:`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object h

Comment: sorry still trying to figure out stackoverflow formatting

Comment: Thank you... You can edit you answer and put your code in nswer part

Comment: No.. still I have error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'page_source'`

Answer (score 5):

This error occurs when we call unicode objects as a function. For example:

```
a = u'this is unicode string'
```

if you do `a()` somewhere in code you get this error

In your case as pointed out `page_source` is a unicode string and not a callable function. So this `page_source(url`) is giving above error.